# How do I add a Title to a Seaborn Clustermap?

Tags: python, charts, visualization, seaborn

I have searched, but not yet discovered how to add a title to a Seaborn Clustermap.

I have tried:

```
plt.title('Title',loc='center')
```

but this adds the title to the legend, rather than the main Clustermap.

I have also tried, creating an axes object first and adding the title to this (which seems to work for the Heatmap), but the problem is that the Clustermap does not plot on this axes object.  It plots on its own object apparently.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `.fig.suptitle('Your Title')`.

Imagine [this example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) from the Seaborn documentation for a clustermap:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
g = sns.clustermap(iris)
```

You add a title with:

```
g = sns.clustermap(iris).fig.suptitle('Your Title')
```

Or simply:

```
g.fig.suptitle('Your Title')
```

However, this adds a title to the whole figure and not to single subplots. If you want to add a title to a subplot, see @Kiraly Sandor's solution.

[image]

```
g.fig.suptitle('Figure Title')
g.ax_heatmap.set_title('Subplot Title')
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer.

Comment: You may also want to adjust the position of the suptitle with `g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=.9)` afterwards, since otherwise there will often be a large ugly gap between the plot and the title. I also like to use `g.ax_col_dendrogram.set_title()`, which adds the title directly above the top dendogram.

Comment: Thanks for answer  ! How to change the fontsize  ?

Answer (score 3):

One of the solutions could be this: the object returned by the plot has an `ax_heatmap` method that has a `set_title` method. If you set it with a title your plot will have one:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
g = sns.clustermap(iris)
g.ax_heatmap.set_title('lalal')
```

However this approach adds a title above your heatmap and not the whole plot.